# Java HashMap wont insert duplications

Tags: java

I am trying to put count of characters into hashMap but it wont insert.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           str1.put(s.charAt(i),
                   str1.getOrDefault(str1.get(s.charAt(i)), 0) + 1);
           str2.put(t.charAt(i),
                   str2.getOrDefault(str2.get(t.charAt(i)) ,0) + 1);
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's a hashmap. Keys are unique.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern is:

```
str1.put(s.charAt(i), 1 + str1.getOrDefault(s.charAt(i), 0));
```

Your current code is doing a lookup, by key, of the current value mapped to the character, which initially will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly fetching the value to increment the count, I would use `compute`.

- basically, if v is null, it initializes to 1.  Otherwise it takes the current value and adds 1.

```
String str = "Programming is fun";
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
       map.compute(str.charAt(i), (k,v)-> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
}
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
 =2
P=1
a=1
r=2
s=1
u=1
f=1
g=2
i=2
m=2
n=2
o=1
```

And you can also do a frequency count using streams.

```
Map<Character, Long> map = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).
          collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s.charAt(0),
                  Collectors.counting()));
```